# How to loop through nested arrays in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I've a nested array in this form

```
tests: [
  [{name:"Bob",score:40,subject:"Math"}, {name:"John",score:55,subject:"Math"}],
  [{name:"Alice",score:70,subject:"English"},{name:"John",score:68,subject:"English"}]
],
// ...
```

and I want to loop through and print while grouping the same subjects together as in:

```
<div *ngFor = "let test of tests;let i = index">
  <ul *ngFor = "let student of test[i] ;let n = index">
     <li>{{student.name+' '+student.score}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but it end up with the error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object `[object Object]` of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

the starts from the second loop. what am I missing here, please?

Comment: Please provide the valid JSON

Comment: Use Object.keys(<Item>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just changed `test[i]` to `test` that is an array and you can iterate it, but `test[i]` is and object and can't be iterate.

ts code:

```
 tests = [
          [{name:"Bob",score:40,subject:"Math"},{name:"John",score:55,subject:"Math"}],
          [{name:"Alice",score:70,subject:"English"},{name:"John",score:68,subject:"English"}]
        ]
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor = "let test of tests;let i = index">
    <ul *ngFor = "let student of test ;let n = index">
        <li>{{student.name+' '+student.score}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvnbct)

Comment: Thanks @Fateme that was quite handy. MashaAllah

Comment: please explain what changes you did , also by `ul` got replaced with `div`

Answer (score 1):

If that's your array, you loop it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let test of tests">
  <ul *ngFor="let student of test">
     <li>{{student.name+' '+student.score}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not angular developer but try for loop :

change `let student of test[i]` to `let student of tests[i]` or `let student of test`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 let tests = [
              [{name:"Bob",score:40,subject:"Math"},{name:"John",score:55,subject:"Math"}],
              [{name:"Alice",score:70,subject:"English"},{name:"John",score:68,subject:"English"}]
            ];

<div *ngFor="let test of tests">
    <ul *ngFor="let student of test">
       <li>{{student.name+' '+student.score}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```