# Display the value that is in an object array

Tags: html, angular, multidimensional-array

The structure of the object array is presented like this:

```js
MET = [
  {
    LABEL: "WILHELMSEN",
    ISINCODE: "NO0010571698",
    RECORD_DATE: "2022-09-16",
    EVENT_DATE: "2022-09-30",
    EVENT_TYPE: "AG Ordinaire",
    SOLDE: 15000.0,
    NUMERO_AG: 10642,
    CREAT_DATE: "2022-04-01",
    MOD_DATE: "2022-04-01",
    EMETTEUR: "408659",
    DEPOSITAIRE: "CA000005775300",
    ISCONFIRMED: 1,
    ISSRD2ELIGIBLE: 1,
    ADRESSE1: "Strand 20",
    ADRESSE2: "",
    LOCALITE: "LYS",
    CODEPOSTAL: 0,
    PAYS: "NOR",
    STATUTAG: 9,
    URL: "",
    RESOLUTION: [
      {
        REF: "01",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I managed to display `MET` array values like for example `LABEL`, `ISINCODE`.

I'm stuck displaying the `REF` value, the value doesn't display and I don't get an error message. And therefore, I don't know where I should work to solve this problem.

I think it's my loop that's not good?

```
<tr *ngFor="let l of MET.RESOLUTION">
    <td>{{ l.MET.RESOLUTION.REF }} </td>
</tr>
```

The code:

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="MET">
   <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>
   <table class="mb-5">
      <tr>
         <th>Isin</th>
         <th>Denomination</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let line of MET">
         <td>{{ line.ISINCODE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.LABEL }} </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <br />
   <table class=" mb-5 ">
      <tr>
         <th>Code</th>
      </tr>
      <ng-container>
         <tr *ngFor="let l of MET.RESOLUTION">
            <td>{{ l.MET.RESOLUTION.REF }} </td>
         </tr>
      </ng-container>
   </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it work with `l.REF`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through nested arrays in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895491/how-to-loop-through-nested-arrays-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate with `MET.RESOLUTION` directly. But you have to iterate the objects in `MET` first, then follow by its `RESOLUTION`. Thus, a nested `*ngFor` is needed.

```
<tr *ngFor="let l of MET">
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let l of l.RESOLUTION">
      <span>{{ l.REF }}</span>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpepcg?file=src/main.component.html)